# Primitive recursive bounds for multidimensional polynomial vdW / HJ

Tags: co.combinatorics, lo.logic, polynomials, additive-combinatorics, ramsey-theory

In Shelah's [paper](https://shelah.logic.at/papers/679/) [679](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0003163), he proves primitive recursive bounds for the polynomial Hales-Jewett theorem and thus for the polynomial van der Waerden theorem.

How about for the multidimensional polynomial HJ and multidimensional polynomial vdW theorems?  In particular, for the "multidimensional polynomial van der Waerden theorem" -- see e.g. Theorem B of [Bergelson-Leibman](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1996-9-03/S0894-0347-96-00194-4/S0894-0347-96-00194-4.pdf) which does the density version (and the corresponding "multidimensional polynomial Hales-Jewett") -- can we obtain primitive recursive bounds?

I do think that Shelah's method probably can be used or maybe does get a primitive recursive bound for all of these questions, but I am not very familiar with it.  I use the multidimensional polynomial vdW theorem in [a recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.08901) and I want to know if the bounds there can actually be made primitive recursive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a standard fact that the (linear) Hales--Jewett theorem tensorizes to yield its multidimensional version. The same observation applies to the polynomial version.

I will describe the idea for the two-dimensional case: assume that $n=2k$ is an even integer, $A$ is a finite alphabet and $c:A^{[n]^2}\to [r]$ is an $r$-coloring. Split the discrete interval $[n]$ into two successive subintervals $I_0:=[k]$ and $I_1:=\{k+1,\dots,2k\}$; this induces a partition of the index set $[n]^2$ into four squares $I_0\times I_0$, $I_0\times I_1$, $I_1\times I_0$ and $I_1\times I_1$ that are all isomorphic to $[k]^2$. Therefore, the $r$-coloring $c$ also induces an $r$-coloring of $(A^4)^{[k]^2}$, which I shall denote by $C$. Then observe that a monochromatic, with respect to $C$, polynomial combinatorial line of $(A^4)^{[k]^2}$ unfolds to a two-dimensional polynomial combinatorial subspace of $A^{[n]^2}$ that is monochromatic with respect to $c$. Note that this subspace is quite special: its wildcard sets are successive and have the same size.

This argument yields the estimate
$$ MPHJ(d,m,k,r) \leq PHJ(d,k^{m^d},r), $$
where

- $PHJ(d,k,r)$ denotes the polynomial Hales--Jewett number, that is, the least positive integer $N$ such that for every integer $n\geq N$ and every alphabet $A$ with $k$ letters, an arbitrary $r$-coloring $c:A^{[n]^d}\to [r]$ has a monochromatic polynomial combinatorial line, and
- $MPHJ(d,m,k,r)$ denotes the corresponding multidimensional polynomial Hales--Jewett number, that is, the least positive integer $N$ such that for every integer $n\geq N$ and every alphabet $A$ with $k$ letters, an arbitrary $r$-coloring $c:A^{[n]^d}\to [r]$ has a monochromatic $m$-dimensional polynomial combinatorial subspace.

The paper of Shelah you cited has an ingenious proof that the shows that, for every fixed dimension $d$, the function $(k,r) \mapsto PHJ(d,k,r)$ is upper bounded by a primitive recursive function that belongs to the class $\mathcal{E}_{7+3d}$ of Grzegorczyk’s hierarchy. (Here, the constants are most likely not optimal, but the linear dependence on the dimension $d$ is necessary.) The same paper also has a proof that claims that the polynomial Hales--Jewett numbers are upper bounded by a primitive recursive function (namely, we have a uniform control of their growth as the dimension $d$ increases) but that proof is problematic (see Fact 4.7 in the first preprint).

Summing up, for every fixed dimension $d$, the function $(m,k,r)\mapsto MPHJ(d,m,k,r)$ is upper bounded by a primitive recursive function that belongs to the class $\mathcal{E}_{7+3d}$ of Grzegorczyk’s hierarchy. From this, one can easily extract bounds for the multidimensional polynomial Van der Waerden theorem.

Comment: Great!  I think I do need something independent of d to actually get primitive recursive bounds in my paper.  It would be nice if someone could fix the "problematic" proof...